# Pandas missing values and groupby boolean

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, missing-data

I found some strange behavior with **groupby** and missing values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "A": [2, 1, 1, 2, 2], "B": [False, np.nan, False, np.nan, False]})
```

Now computing the groupby I obtain:

```
>>> dfB.groupby('A')['B'].nunique()
A
1    1
2    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Is this a bug in pandas? By default we have **dropna=True**. Thus I think we should have 1 entry for each of them.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in pandas that has been fixed. The fix will be included as part of the next release of pandas (1.0).

Answer (score 1):

I think bug, possible solution is pass [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
print (df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(pd.Series.nunique))
```

Or:

```
print (df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(pd.Series.nunique))
A
1    1
2    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```